# Inserting data in database using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert the data in database using c# but i am getting error
here is my code

```
string @admission_no = txtAddmissionNo.Text;
string @student_name = txtStudentName.Text;
string @father_name = txtSDof.Text;
string @receipt_no=txtReceiptNo.Text;
string @acedemic_year = academic_year.Text;
string @selectdate = dtpSD.Text;
string @Class = txtClass.Text;
string @section = txtSection.Text;
string @roll_no = txtRollNo.Text;
string query = "INSERT INTO details( Admission_no,First_Name,Father_name,recepit_no,selectdate,acedemic_year,class1,section,roll_no)values( @admission_no , @student_name,@father_name,@receipt_no,@selectdate,@acedemic_year,@Class,@section ,@roll_no)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

it is giving error u must be declare @admission _no

Comment: You didn't add parameters to your command. And you didn't need to use `@` before your all string values. Use it only with your parameter definitions.

Comment: I'd really like to know why you accepted the answer posted over an hour after mine?

Comment: i really thank's to u ,u had solved the problem first

Comment: u write in comment hoe can i accept?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
try{ 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@admission_no" , SqlDbType.Varchar,20).Value=txtAddmissionNo.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@student_name" , SqlDbType.Varchar,50).Value=txtStudentName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@father_name" , SqlDbType.Varchar,50).Value=txtSDof.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@receipt_no" , SqlDbType.Varchar,20).Value=txtReceiptNo.Text;

    .... add other parameters and its value

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You haven't added any parameters to your `SqlCommand`.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@admission _no", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value
         = @admission_no;

...
```

You need to do that for EVERY parameter defined with an `@` in the insert query string.

You probably got confused by declaring `C#` variables with an `@` sign, which quotes vars and allows you to have a variable name the same name as a C# keyword (such as `MyEventType @event`). This is usually not a great idea as it makes code harder to read IMO.

As @Soner Gönül also noted in his comment, use an `@` only with your parameter definitions